# Reactjs -- cannot setState within button listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My application has two pages: **Main** and **CreateProfile**. React-router is used for navigation.

**User Flow**

1. Start on **Main**
2. Navigate to **CreateProfile** with `hashHistory.push('/register');`
3. Navigate back to **Main** with `hashHistory.push('/');`
4. After rendering **Main**, it appears that React-Router automatically `POPS` **Main**, but
   **Main** doesn't unmount

Afterward, I can successfully update state within **Main**'s `componentWillReceiveProps()`. However, when the user clicks a button within **Main** and the button's listener invokes `this.setState({ ... })`, I get the following error.

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.

It appears that the button listener has an outdated reference to `this.state`.

**How can I resolve this?**

**Edit:** This might not be a react-router specific problem. It could be that listeners are not bound correctly, but I cannot confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that, within `render()`, I was invoking arrow-functions. Consequently, they had an outdated `this` bound to them. The below code works.

```
_renderListItem() {
  return <ListItem
    onTouchTap={
      () => {
        this.setState({foo: 'bar'})
      }
    }
    primaryText={'Test'}
  />
}

render() {
  return (
    <List>
      {this._renderListItem()}
    </List>
  )
}
```

However, I will get the error (below), if I were to change from

`_renderListItem() { ... }`

to the arrow-style

`_renderListItem = () => { ... }`

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused because you're calling `this.setState({..})` inside the constructor. Instead, try to call it inside `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` ;)

EDIT: React router does not unmount the component, but it does pass the new props. These can be captured using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

Comment: `this.setState({..})` is called after the user clicks a button within **Main**, not within its constructor. Something like `<div onClick={() => { this.setState({..}) } } />`. I updated my question for clarity.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` does get invoked. Within it, I can successfully update state. However, my listener (the one that tries to set state and fail) seems to have an alternate, out-dated reference to state. This is not a race condition; it permanently has an outdated reference. I believe this is why I get `Warning: setState(...):...`.